# How to clear the Input feilds and datefeilds in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I try many ways to fix this clear function issue. I used another state for jobNo to fix the clear issue but it didn't works. when i click the clear button state variable values are clear but UI values shows it didn't change how to do that I try many ways . how to fix this it can use form ref or something to clear

```
return (
    <div>
        <Breadcrumb>
            <Breadcrumb.Item>Dashboard</Breadcrumb.Item>
            <Breadcrumb.Item>Notification</Breadcrumb.Item>
        </Breadcrumb>
        <div style={{marginTop: "12px"}}>
            <Row>
                <Text className="breadcrumb__title color--primary">
                    View All Notifications
                </Text>
            </Row>
        </div>
        <Row gutter={8} style={{marginTop: "12px"}}>
            <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={24} lg={24} xl={24}>
                <Card>
                    <Collapse defaultActiveKey={['1']} style={{marginTop: 8}}>
                        <Panel header="Section Filter" key="1">
                            <Form>
                                <Row gutter={[24, 16]}>
                                    {/*<Col xs={24} sm={24} md={12} lg={12} xl={6}>*/}
                                    {/*    <Row gutter={10} style={{marginBottom: 8}}>*/}
                                    {/*        <Col span={8} className={"inquiry-filter-lbl-input"}>*/}
                                    {/*            <span>From Date</span>*/}
                                    {/*        </Col>*/}
                                    {/*        <Col span={16} className={"inquiry-filter-input"}>*/}
                                    {/*            <Form.Item name="fromDate">*/}
                                    {/*                <DatePicker placeholder="Select From Date"*/}
                                    {/*                            style={{width: '100%'}}/>*/}
                                    {/*            </Form.Item>*/}
                                    {/*        </Col>*/}
                                    {/*    </Row>*/}
                                    {/*</Col>*/}
                                    {/*<Col xs={24} sm={24} md={12} lg={12} xl={6}>*/}
                                    {/*    <Row gutter={10} style={{marginBottom: 8}}>*/}
                                    {/*        <Col span={8} className={"inquiry-filter-lbl-input"}>*/}
                                    {/*            <span>To Date</span>*/}
                                    {/*        </Col>*/}
                                    {/*        <Col span={16} className={"inquiry-filter-input"}>*/}
                                    {/*            <Form.Item name="toDate">*/}
                                    {/*                <DatePicker placeholder="Select To Date"*/}
                                    {/*                            style={{width: '100%'}}/>*/}
                                    {/*            </Form.Item>*/}
                                    {/*        </Col>*/}
                                    {/*    </Row>*/}
                                    {/*</Col>*/}
                                    <Col span={8}>
                                        <Form.Item
                                            label="Date Range"
                                            name="DateRange"
                                        >
                                            <RangePicker onChange={value => handleRangeChange(value)}
                                                         style={{minWidth: 313}}/>
                                        </Form.Item>
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={12} lg={12} xl={6}>
                                        <Row gutter={10} style={{marginBottom: 8}}>
                                            <Col span={8} className={"inquiry-filter-lbl-input"}>
                                                <span>Job Number</span>
                                            </Col>
                                            <Col span={16} className={"inquiry-filter-input"}>
                                                <Form.Item name="jobNoValue">
                                                    <Input
                                                        placeholder="Enter Job Number"
                                                        value={jobNoValue}
                                                        onChange={handleJobNoChange}
                                                    />
                                                </Form.Item>
                                            </Col>
                                        </Row>
                                    </Col>
                                    {/*<Col xs={24} sm={24} md={12} lg={12} xl={6}>*/}
                                    {/*    <Row gutter={10} style={{marginBottom: 8}}>*/}
                                    {/*        <Col span={8} className={"inquiry-filter-lbl-input"}>*/}
                                    {/*            <span>Select User</span>*/}
                                    {/*        </Col>*/}
                                    {/*        <Col span={16} className={"inquiry-filter-input"}>*/}
                                    {/*            <Form.Item name="user">*/}
                                    {/*                <Select placeholder="Select user"*/}
                                    {/*                        style={{width: '100%'}}*/}
                                    {/*                        options={[*/}
                                    {/*                            {*/}
                                    {/*                                value: 'jack',*/}
                                    {/*                                label: 'Jack',*/}
                                    {/*                            },*/}
                                    {/*                        ]}*/}
                                    {/*                />*/}
                                    {/*            </Form.Item>*/}
                                    {/*        </Col>*/}
                                    {/*    </Row>*/}
                                    {/*</Col>*/}
                                </Row>

                                <Row className="form-row">
                                    <Col span={24}>
                                        <div style={{float: 'right', marginTop: 16}}>
                                            <Button
                                                style={{marginRight: 10}}
                                                icon={<ClearOutlined/>}
                                                onClick={handleClear}
                                            >
                                                Clear
                                            </Button>
                                            <Button
                                                type="primary"
                                                icon={<SearchOutlined/>}
                                                htmlType={"submit"}
                                                onClick={getNotificationList}
                                            >
                                                Search
                                            </Button>
                                        </div>
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
                            </Form>
                        </Panel>
                    </Collapse>
                    <Spin spinning={loading}>
                        <List
                            itemLayout="horizontal"
                            dataSource={notificationItemList}
                            renderItem={item => (
                                <List.Item>
                                    <Alert showIcon className="notification-alert"
                                        /*unread-notification - add this class if notification status is unread*/
                                           icon={<Avatar
                                               className={item.avatarClass}
                                               icon={<InfoOutlined/>}
                                           />}
                                           message={
                                               <div className="clickable-div" onClick={event => {
                                                   viewJobView(item.indexKey)
                                               }}>
                                                   <Row>
                                                       <Col span={12}>
                        <span className="notification-job-no">
                          {item.jobNo}
                        </span>
                                                       </Col>
                                                       {/*<Col span={12} className="notification-tags">*/}
                                                       {/*    <Tag color="#FF9800">*/}
                                                       {/*        PENDING*/}
                                                       {/*    </Tag>*/}
                                                       {/*    <Tag color="#108ee9">*/}
                                                       {/*        CONVENTIONAL*/}
                                                       {/*    </Tag>*/}
                                                       {/*</Col>*/}
                                                   </Row>
                                               </div>
                                           }
                                           description={
                                               <div className="clickable-div" onClick={event => {
                                                   viewJobView(item.indexKey)
                                               }}>
                                                   <Row>
                                                       <Col span={24}>
                        <span className="notification-description">
                          {item.description}
                        </span>
                                                       </Col>
                                                       <Col span={24} className="col-date-user">
                                                           <div className="notification-user">
                                                               <span className="user-span-lbl">User : </span>
                                                               <span className="user-span-value">
                            {item.lastForwardUser}
                          </span>
                                                           </div>
                                                           <div className="notification-date">
                          <span className="date-span-value">
                            {item.notificationDateTime ? item.notificationDateTime.substring(0, 19) : ''}
                          </span>
                                                           </div>
                                                       </Col>
                                                   </Row>
                                               </div>
                                           }
                                           type="info"

                                    />

                                </List.Item>
                            )}
                        />
                    </Spin>
                </Card>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    </div>
   );
 }

 export default NotificationCenter;
```

Comment: Why are you using to useStates to handle a single value .

    const [searchData, setSearchData] = useState<AllNotificationSearchDto>({
        fromDate: '',
        toDate: '',
        jobNo: ''
    });

const [jobNoValue, setJobNoValue] = useState(searchData.jobNo)

Comment: Keep all the values inside searchdata as separate useStates or update the single object in search data